# Sanitizing inputs to MongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb, code-injection, pymongo

I'm writing a REST interface to a MongoDB database program, and I'm trying to implement search functionality. I'd like to expose the entire MongoDB interface. I have two questions, really, but they're related so I'm putting them in one post:

1. Is it safe to decode untrusted JSON with the Python json module, or is it like the pickle module in that it could allow arbitrary code execution?
2. Is it safe to pass that decoded JSON to the PyMongo find() function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python's JSON module should be safe to use with untrusted input, at least in its default configuration (i.e. you haven't supplied any of the custom decoders, which could potentially have exploits within them).

However, we cannot say with certainty that the results of `json.loads()` are safe to pass to pymongo's `find()` method. While the `find()` method will not modify (update or remove) data in mongodb, it is possible to craft intentionally very poorly performing queries, like the following which uses a specially-crafted `$where` clause to create very poor performance characteristics:

```
{"$where": "function() { for (var i=0; i<1000000; i++) {}; return true; }"}
```

Note that this is both valid JSON, and a valid mongodb query against.

For this reason, I wouldn't permit user-crafted JSON to be used directly as a query against mongodb, unless your users are all trusted (i.e. clients that you control directly, such as other servers/components within an application).

Comment: Can you give the same answer for Java and Scala?

Comment: I think the same logic applies to any language or framework; there are certain sorts of inputs which can cause bad behavior on the MongoDB server (such as the `$where` example above), so, as a rule, passing un-validated, un-verified input directly from end users to the database is a bad idea if it can be avoided. The best way to sanitize user input is with a form validation library, and a set of (recursive?) algorithms to convert the validated form objects to a MongoDB document (a `dict` in Python, say) for query/update/insert/etc.

Comment: thanks. I am trying to make a tool that can detect such "bad patterns" automatically. Hence I need a comprehensive list of examples.

Comment: Since MongoDB allows arbitrary javascript code in `$where`, you won't be able to do this with any generality (NB: this is the halting problem). You could adopt a rule which says that any `$where` is considered unsafe, but that might be too aggressive depending on your needs. Outside of `$where`, saving or querying for anything should be generally safe, from a database perspective -- it may not be safe from the application's perspective (i.e. if you allowed end-users to override an "is_admin" flag, for example).