# Pymongo ORM injection? Sanitizing input

Tags: python, mongodb, sql-injection, pymongo, sanitization

I think do you know sql injections, and the same for nosql, called orm injection.
I am using pymongo and mongodb, I have user controlled input for a simple find() and for a find with a $regexp operator.
How do I 'sanitize' that inputs?

Comment: I wrote another answer on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099301/nosql-injection-in-python/13100786#13100786

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you speak of *ORM injections* then you speak of relational database systems and not really MongoDB or NoSQL systems in total.
PyMongo is not an ORM tool and therefore ORM injections do not take place.

The MongoDB find operation will not modify or delete any data in your collection. So you are quite safe with untrusted inputs.

The only thing that could happen, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278238/sanitizing-inputs-to-mongodb), is that a bad query could slow your system down by doing something like this:

```
{"$where": "function() { for (var i=0; i<1000000; i++) {}; return true; }"}
```

This means you could make sure in your code, that no functions are transferred via the user parameters.

Comment: What do you mean with "This means you could make sure in your code, that no functions are transferred via the user parameters." please can you bring us an example?

Comment: I already gave the example. Make sure that the user does not write something like I showed in my answer as a where statement. So for example make sure that the where string does not contain the substring "function()".

Comment: I don't have a $where, just e $regexp. Or am i missing something?

Comment: Yeah, if the user input is only a part of your regex, you don't have anything like injections or function-alling to fear in your query!

Comment: I don't know a great deal about mongo injection, but just because you aren't modifying data doesn't mean that you can't expose sensitive data. If you can split a find command into two finds then you could expose some sensitive data.